# writing make files

Tags: makefile

Can anyone point me to some good tutorials on the make utility.
Something that will take me through beginners to advanced and let me write and understand professional make file which come with various linux packages.

some book also might help.

I googled for this , but there are so many. I dont know which one to read.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out "Managing Projects with GNU Make (Nutshell Handbooks)" book from ORielly publication. It is a nice book for understanding Make Utility.

You can find the details at: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596006101?tag=flazx-20&camp=14573&creative=327641&linkCode=as1&creativeASIN=0596006101&adid=0EN45W92PQCA28N8JJW2&](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101)

Comment: You beat me to it. :-)  This book will serve you well, and it covers several different versions of Make. Buy it; you won't regret doing so.

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) is quite complete and contains many examples.